# scikit-learn - predict trained model on new input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset like below:

```
| "Consignor Code" | "Consignee Code" | "Origin" | "Destination" | "Carrier Code" | 
|------------------|------------------|----------|---------------|----------------| 
| "6402106844"     | "66903717"       | "DKCPH"  | "CNPVG"       | "6402746387"   | 
| "6402106844"     | "66903717"       | "DKCPH"  | "CNPVG"       | "6402746387"   | 
| "6402106844"     | "6404814143"     | "DKCPH"  | "CNPVG"       | "6402746387"   | 
| "6402107662"     | "66974631"       | "DKCPH"  | "VNSGN"       | "6402746393"   | 
| "6402107662"     | "6404518090"     | "DKCPH"  | "THBKK"       | "6402746393"   | 
| "6402107662"     | "6404518090"     | "DKBLL"  | "THBKK"       | "6402746393"   | 
| "6408507648"     | "6403601344"     | "DKCPH"  | "USTPA"       | "66565231"     |
```

I am trying to build my very first ML model on it. For that, I am using scikit-learn. This is my code:

```py
#Import the dependencies
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

#Import the dataset (A CSV file)
dataset = pd.read_csv('shipments.csv', header=0, skip_blank_lines=True)
#Drop any rows containing NaN values
dataset.dropna(subset=['Consignor Code', 'Consignee Code',
                       'Origin', 'Destination', 'Carrier Code'], inplace=True)

#Convert the numeric only cells to strings
dataset['Consignor Code'] = dataset['Consignor Code'].astype('int64')
dataset['Consignee Code'] = dataset['Consignee Code'].astype('int64')
dataset['Carrier Code'] = dataset['Carrier Code'].astype('int64')

#Define our target (What we want to be able to predict)
target = dataset.pop('Destination')

#Convert all our data to numeric values, so we can use the .fit function.
#For that, we use LabelEncoder
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
target = le.fit_transform(list(target))
dataset['Origin'] = le.fit_transform(list(dataset['Origin']))
dataset['Consignor Code'] = le.fit_transform(list(dataset['Consignor Code']))
dataset['Consignee Code'] = le.fit_transform(list(dataset['Consignee Code']))
dataset['Carrier Code'] = le.fit_transform(list(dataset['Carrier Code']))

#Prepare the dataset.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)


#Prepare the model and .fit it.
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Make a prediction on the test set.
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

#Print the accuracy score.
print("Accuracy score: {}".format(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)))
```

Now above code returns:

```
Accuracy score: 0.7172413793103448
```

Now my question might be stupid - but how can I use my `model` to actually show me what it predicts on new data?

Consider below **new input**, and I want it to predict the `Destination`:

```
"6408507648","6403601344","DKCPH","","66565231"
```

How can query my model with this data and get the predicted `Destination` out?

Comment: Just call `model.predict` on the new data exactly like you did on `X_test`. `X_test` should be identical in structure to any new data.

Comment: BTW - you should put your label encoder and any other preprocessing like that into a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). It's a serious error to do preprocessing like that before you split your data.

Comment: I doubt it will work. You will have some trouble with the encoder, because of the `fit_transform()`. Also, I'm finding it weird you are training the data with 4 variables, but your input contains 5.

Comment: If i do `print(predictions)` I get a list that looks like: `[244 217 90 ... 262 259 244]` - I am not sure what this means? Does my test data needs to have the `Destination` column populated?

Comment: @CeliusStingher Where do you see that? Sorry, I might be missing something very obvious here, as this is my first ML endeavors.

Comment: The `predictions` array are the values predicted for each individual X_test values.

Comment: You can recover your destinations by using the inverse transform from the label encoder. What you are seeing are the integer codes that the label encoder encoded your destination strings as. But again, it is a serious error to do the encoding before your train test split. If you use a pipeline, it will be much easier to avoid such an error.

Comment: Using `fit_transforms()` fits the encoder to the passed dataset, and then it makes the transformation. If you need to encode new values (the inputs) it will fit with the new data and it won't match the values the model was trained with. You should fit different instances of the encoder for each variable, then `transform` so you can `transform` new data (you want to use to predict) with the same encoding.

Comment: @Dan Using `le.inverse_transform(predictions)` gives me `ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: [83, 85, 87, 90 ..........]`

Comment: This is what I mean with the comment above @oliverbj

Comment: See @CeliusStingher comment directly above. You need one label encoder per feature / target you want to encode. The state that the label encoder object stores gets set when you call `fit` and recalled when you call `transform` or `inverse_transform`. You are overriding it each time you call `fit_transform` on a different column. Don't do that.

Comment: But also, seriously, use a pipeline.

Comment: Ah... Sorry guys, this is very confusing for me. I guess I have to dig into the documentation a bit more. Would one of you mind just giving a small example of how to predict using a simple input (like a CSV) - or maybe even some pseudo-code. I have a hard time wrapping my head around the scikit-learn documenation.

Comment: @oliverbj I added a quick answer as an illustration to try explain what is being discussed above (except for pipelines). Let me know if that clears it up at all.

Comment: Could you check my answer? Please make sure to let me know if any problem pops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a full working example with the prediction included. The most important part is to define the different label encoders for each feature, so you can fit the new data with the same encoding, otherwise you will run into errors (which might now show, but you will notice when you compute accuracy):

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Consignor Code':["6402106844","6402106844","6402106844","6402107662","6402107662","6402107662","6408507648"],
                   'Consignee Code': ["66903717","66903717","6404814143","66974631","6404518090","6404518090","6403601344"],
                   'Origin':["DKCPH","DKCPH","DKCPH","DKCPH","DKCPH","DKBLL","DKCPH"],
                   'Destination':["CNPVG","CNPVG","CNPVG","VNSGN","THBKK","THBKK","USTPA"],
                   'Carrier Code':["6402746387","6402746387","6402746387","6402746393","6402746393","6402746393","66565231"]})

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

#Import the dataset (A CSV file)
#Drop any rows containing NaN values
dataset.dropna(subset=['Consignor Code', 'Consignee Code',
                       'Origin', 'Destination', 'Carrier Code'], inplace=True)


#Define our target (What we want to be able to predict)
target = dataset.pop('Destination')

#Convert all our data to numeric values, so we can use the .fit function.
#For that, we use LabelEncoder
le_origin = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_consignor = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_consignee = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_carrier = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le_target = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
target = le_target.fit_transform(list(target))
dataset['Origin'] = le_origin.fit_transform(list(dataset['Origin']))
dataset['Consignor Code'] = le_consignor.fit_transform(list(dataset['Consignor Code']))
dataset['Consignee Code'] = le_consignee.fit_transform(list(dataset['Consignee Code']))
dataset['Carrier Code'] = le_carrier.fit_transform(list(dataset['Carrier Code']))

#Prepare the dataset.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


#Prepare the model and .fit it.
model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Make a prediction on the test set.
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

#Print the accuracy score.
print("Accuracy score: {}".format(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)))

new_input = ["6408507648","6403601344","DKCPH","66565231"]
fitted_new_input = np.array([le_consignor.transform([new_input[0]])[0],
                                le_consignee.transform([new_input[1]])[0],
                                le_origin.transform([new_input[2]])[0],
                                le_carrier.transform([new_input[3]])[0]])
new_predictions = model.predict(fitted_new_input.reshape(1,-1))

print(le_target.inverse_transform(new_predictions))
```

### Finally, your tree predicts:

```
['THBKK']
```

Comment: The lines were I define the multiple encoders, can be done easier with the `for loop` dan showed, or maybe easier with a dict comprehension. Feel free to accept my answer if it helps you solve the issue as now you can make predictions with new data with this code :)

Comment: You really should do the train test split before the encoding though, otherwise it's technically a target leak.

Comment: @Celius Wow! Thank you so much. This gives me a great starting point. May I ask regarding the finally prediction? On my dataset (>8k rows), it gives me a final prediction of `SGSIN` with an accuracy of `0.71`. However, the final prediction is different every time I run the code. For this specific input, ideal would be to return `USTPA`. How can I improve it?

Comment: You can start by fixing `random_state` to make sure the model can be replicated (generate always the same result), both for the `train_test_split` and for the `RandomForest`. Also, you might want to check in hyperparameter tuning for better optimization. I just edited my answer to fix the random state in the `RandomForest`. Check for `max_depth`, `min_child_weight`, `max_features` and some other hyperparameters you can tune to improve its performance.

Comment: Good and challenging question anyhow :)

Comment: @CeliusStingher Thank you! I updated the code with the random state, and it does indeed generate the same result. Now my question is: should the `random_state` be "enabled" when using this in production?

Comment: Yes for the sake of your customer / client you should have it enabled. This will ensure it is reproducible which is very important from the client's side, otherwise they will get random results and (if they don't have an understanding of how a RandomForest classifier works) you will immediately questioned on why are they getting different (inconsistent in their eyes) results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something quick to illustrate the point. I wouldn't do it this way in practice and there are probably some errors. For example, I think this will fail if there are unseen classes in the test set.

```
#Prepare the dataset.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

#Convert all our data to numeric values, so we can use the .fit function.
#For that, we use LabelEncoder
le_target = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_train = le_target.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = le_target.transform(y_test)

# Now create a separate encoder for each of your features:
encoders = {}
for feature in ["Origin", "Consignor Code", "Consignee Code", "Carrier Code"]:
# NOTE: The LabelEncoder docs state clearly at the start that you shouldn't be using it on your inputs. I'm not going to get into that here though but just be aware that it's not a good encoding.
    encoders[feature] = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    X_train[feature] = encoders[feature].fit_transform(X_train[feature])
    X_test[feature] = encoders[feature].transform(X_test[feature])    

#Prepare the model and .fit it.
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Make a prediction on the test set.
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

le_target.inverse_transform(predictions)
```

The key concepts for you here are to use separate encoders for your features because these encoder objects remember how to encode that feature. This is done in the `fit` stage. You then need to call `transform` on any new data to encode that correctly.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me!